# FFMPEG converting FLAC to MP3 changes front cover image format and size

Tags: ffmpeg

Im using this command

```
ffmpeg -i "input.flac" -b:a 320k "output.mp3"
```

it copies all metadata to the mp3 but convert the front cover from jpg to png i want to keep the same cover file from flac to mp3

[Original FLAC front cover 1200x1200 JPG 900 KB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ahu5.png)

[Converted MP3 front cover 1200x1200 PNG 2 MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV8h3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cover art presents as a video stream with ffmpeg, so `-c:v copy` (AKA `-codec:v copy`) preserves the format and size.

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -b:a 320k -c:v copy output.mp3
```